# Update a python dictionary w/ lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm struggling to update a dictionary of lists using loops.

```py
weather_dict = \
{
"texas": [],
"colorado": = [],
"virginia": = [],
"illinois": = [],
"california": = []
}

arbitrary_weather = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

My goal is to have the values of 
`arbitrary_weather`
pushed into lists within the dictionary using loops. The correlation map is sequential, `arbitrary_weather[0] --> texas[]`, 
`arbitrary_weather[1] --> colorado[]`, etc. With every iteration of the code, arbitrary_weather is going to change, but the dictionary will continue to append its lists in the same sequential order.

I'm relatively new to python, but working on a graduate project that is going to accumulate a lot of data over time. Eventually, the lists of data within the dictionary will be analyzed using python panda. I have never used panda, so if possible, it would be tremendously helpful to learn best practices for building dictionaries used in data analytics.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not python syntax...

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected the syntax mistake in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make sure the the number of keys in dictionary always equal the len of the list then you can loop through the dictionary and add one at a time

```
weather_dict = {
    "texas" : [],
    "colorado" : [],
    "virginia" : [],
    "illinois" : [],
    "california" : []
}

arbitrary_weather = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
i = 0
for k in weather_dict: 
   weather_dict[k].append(arbitrary_weather[i])
   i += 1

print(weather_dict)
```

**EDIT:**

Note that python 3.6 and below iterate through dict is not ordered, if you using python 3.6 and below I suggest using the answer made by Mad Physicist of turning keys into a list so it's ordered

Comment: Note that in this particular instance `for k, v in weather_dict.items():` can simply be `for k in weather_dict:`.

Comment: This worked, thank you for your help! I'm going to take up your suggestion and learn how to use Mad Physicist's method of turning keys into a list.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that until python 3.6, dictionaries were not ordered. In fact, you're only using your initial dict as a repository for key names, so I'd recommend storing it as a sequence of key names, not a dictionary with empty values:

```
states = ['Texas', 'Colorado', 'Illinois', 'California']
```

You can turn the initial measurements into a dictionary using a comprehension, and append to the lists after that:

```
weather_dict = {state: [value] for state, value in zip(states, arbitrary_weather)}
```

You can do that even if you keep the original dictionary as a dictionary, since it is iterable over the keys.